# OpenMP generic qsort lackluster speedup

Tags: c, generics, parallel-processing, openmp, qsort

So it seems that my implementation breaks even with the basic serial qsort at around 1 billion elements.  Most parallel qsort algorithms online are for sorting integer arrays and stuff, but I want to be able to sort anything using custom comparators like the built-in qsort because I would like to sort some structs I have.  I'm using 12 threads and can verify they are getting spawned properly looking at top.  Perhaps I'm spawning too many and should stop spawning new threads based on on the depth of recursion?  I know my implementation of qsort is fairly basic and obviously the built-in qsort has had a lot of work and optimization put into it but I fail to see why I'm not getting a good speed-up with the parallelization.  Any input would be greatly appreciated as I could use this code in a lot of areas if I can keep it generic.  Thanks!

```
void test ( void* data, uint64_t startIdx, uint64_t endIdx, size_t dataSize, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *) )
{
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single nowait
        {
            p_qsort( data, 0, MAX_INTS - 1, sizeof (testint), cmp );
        }
    }
}

void p_qsort ( void* data, uint64_t startIdx, uint64_t endIdx, size_t dataSize, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *) )
{
    uint64_t idx = p_qsort_partition( data, startIdx, endIdx, dataSize, cmp );

    //Left array
    if ( startIdx < idx - 1 )
    {
        #pragma omp task
        p_qsort( data, startIdx, idx - 1, dataSize, cmp );
    }
    //Right array
    if ( endIdx > idx )
    {
        #pragma omp task
        p_qsort( data, idx, endIdx, dataSize, cmp );
    }
}

void swapVoidElements ( void* el1, void* el2, size_t size )
{
    if ( el1 == el2 )
        return;

    void* temp = malloc( size );

    //temp = el1
    memcpy( temp, el1, size );
    //el1 = el2
    memcpy( el1, el2, size );
    //el2 = temp
    memcpy( el2, temp, size );

    free( temp );
}

uint64_t p_qsort_partition ( void* data, uint64_t left, uint64_t right, size_t dataSize, int (*cmp)(const void *, const void *) )
{
    void* pivotP = getVoidPtr( data, left, dataSize );
    void* pivotCmp = malloc( dataSize );
    memcpy( pivotCmp, pivotP, dataSize );

    while ( left <= right )
    {
        while ( cmp( getVoidPtr( data, left, dataSize ), pivotCmp ) < 0 )
            left++;
        //while ( array[right] > pivot )
        while ( cmp( getVoidPtr( data, right, dataSize ), pivotCmp ) > 0 )
            right--;
        //Swap
        if ( left <= right )
        {
            void* leftP = getVoidPtr( data, left, dataSize );
            void* rightP = getVoidPtr( data, right, dataSize );

            swapVoidElements( leftP, rightP, dataSize );

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    free( pivotCmp );

    return left;
}

void* getVoidPtr ( void* data, uint64_t idx, size_t dataSize )
{
    uint64_t idxNum = idx * dataSize;
    char* test = ((char*) data) + idxNum;

    return (void *) test;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You incur a bit of overhead for every OMP task you create, and your particular tasks get smaller and smaller.  As the work per task gets small, the overhead becomes proportionally more expensive.  Some of the common optimization techniques for serial QuickSort might help not only with the basic algorithm, but with your overhead problem, too.

You could greatly reduce the total number of tasks involved, and therefore their associated overhead, by switching strategy for small subarrays.  That would line up nicely with the common Quicksort optimization of switching to Insertion Sort for small subarrays.  The definition of "small" is a tunable parameter, and its optimum value depends somewhat on what you're sorting, but possibly something in the range of 5 - 30 would be a good cutoff for you.  When you make such a switch, perform the whole subarray insertion sort in one task.

You might also benefit from recursing only for the smaller of each pair of subarrays, and instead looping to handle the larger.  This limits the maximum recursion depth to O(log n), whereas otherwise it is O(n) in the worst case.  Inasmuch as each recursion involves its own task, this also will cut the total number of tasks required by at least a factor of two.

Choosing good pivots is one of the central issues in QuickSort performance, but the relative effects of pivot choice algorithm are highly data dependent.  I'd suggest something at least a *little* more sophisticated than choosing always the leftmost element -- either median-of-three or random pivot selection is likely to yield somewhat better performance in the average case.  Inasmuch as choice of pivot affects subarray sizes, which is related to the number of tasks created and *their* sizes, this may be an additional win for your parallel version.

Comment: A simple way to avoid the task overhead for small sorts is to call serial qsort when the number of items is below some threshold.  My experience has been that the threshold needs to be on the order of 500 (give or take a few factors of 2) for simple types.  John's advice on a good pivot is important.  In the TBB parallel quicksort, we use a pseudo-median of 9.  See also my blog https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/a-parallel-stable-sort-using-c11-for-tbb-cilk-plus-and-openmp for general parallel sort advice.

Comment: John and Arch, thanks for the great advice.  I will work on insertion sort and optimizing the amount of tasks I am creating, as well as improving pivot selection. :) 
Is there anything strange I'm doing with the void pointers? It's not easy when you can't just call arr[i] = arr[x] or whatever to swap elements because I actually need to copy memory (see the swapVoidElement function).  Are there any improvements I could make with my idea of voids and generalization?  Your help has been greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NateDellinger, your swap function looks fine.  However, if you are willing to assume at least C99, and that the individual objects being sorted are not huge, then you could consider avoiding dynamic memory management by declaring `temp` as a variable-length array: `unsigned char temp[size]`.  That should be cheaper, as it will be allocated on the stack.  In that case you eliminate both the `malloc()` and the `free()`, but leave everything else exactly as it is.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  Wasn't sure how to put void information on the stack.  The built in qsort runs 1bil elements in around 372 seconds.  After the insertion sort and reduction in task calls I got my parallel version down to ~250 seconds.  Then amazingly after I got rid of the malloc/free call in swapelement it dropped to 70-80 seconds!  I think I was bottlenecking with too many calls for heap allocation, so switching to the stack helped out a ton!